# isinstance not working correctly with beautifulsoup(NameError)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nameerror, isinstance

I'm using isinstance to select some html tags and passing them to a Beautifulsoup function. The problem is I keep getting NameErrors from what should be perfectly executable code.

```
def horse_search(tag):
    return (tag.has_attr('href') and isinstance(tag.previous_element, span))

...

for tag in soup.find_all(horse_search):
   print (tag)
```

NameError: global name 'span' is not defined

Also I'm getting errors from the example code in the documentation of Beautifulsoup using isinstance in conjunction with tag.previous_element

```
def surrounded_by_strings(tag):
    return (isinstance(tag.next_element, NavigableString)
            and isinstance(tag.previous_element, NavigableString))

for tag in soup.find_all(surrounded_by_strings):
    print tag.name
```

NameError: global name "NavigableString" is not defined

What could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using those `isinstance` calls? also, show your imports

Comment: Imports are from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, import requests, import re, import time and import random. I'm looking to isolate tags that contain a string I need. Of all the <a> tags there are only a few I need and they're all children to a span tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find all anchors that has a span parent and an href attribute do:

```
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    for a in span.find_all('a'):
        if a.has_attr('href'):
            print a['href']
```

however, while this is nice, as in most cases, using some tool that supports xpath can be even better, for example, using lxml and xpath you code can look as neat as:

```
from lxml import etree
etree.parse(url, etree.HTMLParser()).xpath('//span/a/@href')
```

Comment: Sadly for me, this doesn't answer the question ("What could be wrong" - ie, why are NameErrors being thrown here).