# How to solve this namespace conflict with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble with Python namespaces.

With `import bs4`

```
>>> import bs4
>>> print type(x)
>>> <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
>>> isinstance(x,bs4.element.NavigableString)
>>> True
```

But I want to use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and then I get an error

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> print type(x)
>>> <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
>>> isinstance(x,bs4.element.NavigableString)
>>> ...
NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined


isinstance(x,bs4.element.NavigableString)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             What should go here?
```

Checked also [isinstance not working correctly with beautifulsoup(NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819763/isinstance-not-working-correctly-with-beautifulsoupnameerror) but it didn't help me.

Comment: You need to either `import bs4` **as well**, or add `element` to what you're importing (`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element`) then access that directly (`isinstance(x, element.NavigableString`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer

Comment: For the record (as far as I'm aware) there's nothing wrong with using both `import module` and `from module import function` as long as you're referencing the names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said, replace the import statement with `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element` and the problematic line with `element.NavigableString`.